# Windows default shell and path not found

Tags: c#, python, windows, shell, path

i've changed the Windows default shell with my application and everythings is ok.
My aplication is in c# and i need to run some external python scripts, and here is the error because the Path variable is not found.

I've tried to set the Path for the started process :

```
  process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PATH"] = "c:\\Python27;c:\\Python27\\Scripts";
```

This just dosen't work.

The problem is that the PATH variable is not loaded because i've changed the default windows shell so explorer.exe dosent come up.

Thank you.

Comment: At my windows installation the path variable is "Path" instead of "PATH", maybe is this causing the issue?

Comment: I've tried but got same result

Comment: Do you mean that the application you're having trouble with is the replacement shell, i.e., is being launched instead of Windows Explorer?  I think you might have to P/Invoke CreateEnvironmentBlock() and feed the output into StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.  (The most likely problem with the line of code you've posted is that it doesn't include the other mandatory folders such as c:\windows\system32.  But it is probably best to look up the configured environment variables rather than using a constant string.)